# Breaking when LastError changes

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg

Is there a way to break `windbg` or `visual studio` debugger execution when the value of `LastError` value changes?

**Edit:**
Found a way by setting a breakpoint in `ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error`.

Does anyone know another way or it's the best way for that?

Comment: [GetLastError()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx) is a method. Does your code already call that or do you expect VS or WinDbg to call that? How often do you want it to be checked? Once per millisecond? Once per microsecond?

Comment: It's a method, which checking a value in the TEB of a thread. I want to break in the moment that this value was changed. For now I'm just putting a conditional breakpoint on `ntdll!RtlSetLastWin32Error`, but I was wondering if there is a better way to achieve that.

Comment: If you know the address, you might set a memory breakpoint in WinDbg (`ba w`)

Comment: Maybe you want to include the things you know (described in the comment) into the question. Comments are transient. And you probably don't need an answer that says "set a breakpoint at RtlSetLastWin32Error()". That comment also shows that you have spent some effort and research, which is not so clear with the current version of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set a write breakpoint on the address of teb->LastErrorValue

```
ba w4 @@c++(&(@$thread->LastErrorValue))
```

happy breaking whenever error value changes
you can add conditions to the bp to break only when you want too

```
0:000> ba w4 @@c++(&(@$thread->LastErrorValue)) "!gle;gc"
breakpoint 0 redefined
0:000> g

LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc000008a - Indicates the specified resource type cannot be found in the image file.
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0 - STATUS_WAIT_0
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000034 - Object Name not found.
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0 - STATUS_WAIT_0
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000034 - Object Name not found.
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000034 - Object Name not found.
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000034 - Object Name not found.
LastErrorValue: (Win32) 0 (0) - The operation completed successfully.
LastStatusValue: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000034 - Object Name not found.
```

Comment: Is there a similar way in visual studio?